# Permanently extend symfony twig template

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.6

In my symfony2 application I created a dashboard which currently consists of many navigation elements.
Now I am trying to split those elements into several bundles.

This is the code I have:

```
{# app/Resources/views/base.html.twig #}

{# ... #}
{% block body %} {% endblock %}
{# ... #}
```

Then in the ProfileBundle:

```
{# src/MyApp/ProfileBundle/Resources/views/Dashboard/index.html.twig #}

{% block body %}
    <p>Heading</p>
    <ul>
    {% block dashboardNavi %} {% endblock %}
    </ul>
{% block %}
```

**edit**: The controller:

```
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('MyAppProfileBundle:Dashboard:index.html.twig', array());
    }
}
```

The routing:

```
pricecalc_profile_dashboad_security:
    pattern: /dashboard
    defaults: {_controller: MyAppProfileBundle:Dashboard:index }
```

That template is rendered correctly, when my route "/dashboard" is loaded.

What I now'd like to do, is extend that `dashboardNavi`-Block in multiple Bundles without changing the route from my ProfileBundle.
Each of those Bundles brings it`s own routes and controllers for custom actions, but all bundles should extend that one block to add links for their custom actions to the dashboard screen.

What I have so far is:

```
{# src/MyApp/ProfileNewsletterBundle/Resources/views/Dashboard/indexNewsletter.html.twig #}

{% extends 'MyAppProfileBundle:Dashboard:index.html.twig' %}
{% block dashboardNavi %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
{% endblock %}
```

but that template is never rendered.

**edit 2:**
Maybe my understanding of how symfony is working in terms of template inheritance is kind of wrong. I'll specify what I am trying to do.

I got one Bundle (`DashboardBundle`) which consists of an own route, controller, view etc. The view contains two blocks - like `navigation` and `dashboard`.
Now, I would like to have those two blocks extended by some other Bundles - just adding new navigation items and shortcuts on that `dashboard` and `navigation` block.
I would like to do those enhancements without modifying my Dashboard-Bundle - if that is possible at all.

When finished, I will have 16 Bundles, each providing own functionality in own Controllers - and they should just be linked on that dashboard.
Is it possible to have the dashboard-view extended that way without modifying the view itself?

Comment: Why doesn't work? Any error? Firebug?

Comment: No error, nothing. The template is simply not recognized.

Comment: Can you show some of the controller logic (specifically the render part) in `MyApp/ProfileNewsletterBundle` ? The code pasted so far is fine

Comment: @ThomasPotaire I added the controller / routing for the `MyApp/ProfileBundle`. The `MyApp/ProfileNewsletterBundle` currently does not even have a controller - maybe that`s the problem... I thought, I could simply add the bundle (added that bundle to the AppKernel, though) and the template and have symfony recognize that template to extend the existing one?

Comment: Taking a guess here, your problem might be that Symfony2 won't automatically pick up `Dashboard/indexNewsletter.html.twig`. You must explicitly render it in a controller action. Extending a template in Twig is just like object inheritance.

Comment: pls show your Newsletter controller

Comment: It does not have a separate controller as it currently does not provide any functionality except layout enhancements. How would a controller look like for that issue? I do not want to provide any new functionality - I would just have the new bundle extend the layout of an already existant bundle.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to fix that after having understood how symfony works in extending controllers and views.

I added a new Controller:

```
{# src/MyApp/ProfileNewsletterBundle/Controllers/DashboardController.php #}
class DashboardController extends Controller {
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('ProfileNewsletterBundle:Dashboard:index.html.twig', array());
    }
}
```

modified the bundle `ProfileNewsletterBundle` to let the method `getParent` return `ProfileBundle`,

and modified the view:

```
{% extends 'ProfileBundle:Dashboard:index.html.twig' %}

{% block dashboardNavi %}
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
{% endblock %}
```

That seems to work fine so far.
Thank you all for spending your time on that.